# bash: fill file from another file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file named SOURCE, and I want to create a file named TARGET of a specific length, containing copies of SOURCE.  TARGET's length is not necessarily an integer multiple of SOURCE's length.  I want to do this using bash on Linux.

My first try was this:

```
while true; do cat SOURCE; done | head -c $TARGET_LENGTH > TARGET
```

That hangs after writing the specified number of bytes to TARGET.  How do I make it not hang?  (I suspect I'm missing a detail around how pipes and signals work.)

**Edit:** I know that `while true` runs forever, but I expected the head command to shut everything down after consuming the specified number of bytes.

Comment: `while true; do ...; done` will execute forever. You need to tell `while` when and how to stop.

Comment: `while true` runs forever... And the `head` command knows nothing about there being a `while` in front of it, so can't "shut everything down". I'd probably use something like `awk` to do this.

Comment: If you want a really funny solution (but hey, it's a joke solution, don't use it seriously): `yes "$(< file)" | head -c "$TARGET_LENGTH" > TARGET`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
while cat SOURCE; do true; done | head -c "$TARGET_LENGTH" > TARGET
```

Comment: I think this is what happens: head exits, which closes its stdin, and then cat exits with a non-zero exit code because its stdout is closed, which terminates the loop.

Comment: Very interesting solution to an interesting problem. +1 to both

Answer (score 1):

Here's a longwinded solution... Can someone do something more elegant?

```
echo > $TARGET
sourceLength=`wc -c $SOURCE | awk '{print $1}'`
let loops=$(( $TARGET_LENGTH/$sourceLength ))

let n=0;
while [ $n -lt $loops ]; do
  let n=$(( $n+1 )) || exit 1
  cat $SOURCE >> $TARGET
done

let mod=$(( $TARGET_LENGTH % $sourceLength ))
head -c $mod $SOURCE >> $TARGET
```

Comment: `head -c 0` does the right thing, so you don't need the `||exit 1`.  And maybe replace the first loop with something like `for i in $(seq 1 $loops); do cat $SOURCE; done > $TARGET`.  If you do that you can eliminate the echo at the beginning too.

Comment: yup, those are good suggestions.   The `|| exit 1` is cruft leftover from debugging a typo.   I'm hoping someone can come up with a one-liner instead of this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out of the while loop.

For example, using a temp file, fill it until it's the same size or larger than your target length, then break out of the loop and use head -c to output the temp file into your target gile.

```
while true; do 
  cat $SOURCE_FILE >> /tmp/temp.out; 
  TMP_LENGTH=$(wc -c /tmp/temp.out |awk '{print $1}')
  if [ $TMP_LENGTH -ge $TARGET_LENGTH ]; then 
    break
  fi
done
head -c $TARGET_LENGTH /tmp/temp.out > $TARGET_FILE
```